# Using Euclid Symbol and Euclid Extra as mathfonts(ttf) by overleaf

Tags: amsmath, unicode-math

is there a way i can turn my maths fonts using the above TrueType(ttf) fonts on Overleaf?,your guidance will be highly appreciated.
Here is my MWE

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % allows loading of system font
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={170mm,257mm},
left=20mm,
top=20mm,
}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Euclid Symbol Regular.ttf}
%\setmathfont{Tiger Expert.ttf}
\setmathfont{Euclid Extra Regular.ttf} % replace with your desired font
\setmainfont{times new roman.ttf}[
ItalicFont = times new roman italic.ttf ,
BoldFont = times new roman bold.ttf ,
BoldItalicFont = times new roman bold italic.ttf,
]
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,labelsep=0.5cm, leftmargin=*]
\item \begin{enumerate}
\item Expand and simplify the binomial expansion $\left(1+\dfrac{x}{5}\right)^7$\hfill(2 marks)
\vspace{5cm}
\item Use the expansion in (a) above to estimate the value of $\left(1.04\right)^7$\hfill(2 marks)
\vspace{4cm}
\end{enumerate}
\item  If $\textbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
5&-1\\
2&2
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\textbf{B}=\begin{pmatrix}
-4&3\\
1&-2
\end{pmatrix}$, find the matrix \textbf{X} such that $3\textbf{A}-2\textbf{B}+3\textbf{X}=0$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see these fonts are not proper math fonts (with a math table and so on). Maybe the best thing you can do is to use some real math font as a base and overload some symbols from these fonts. Or, best is probably to use some real math font.

Comment: You can upload the font file to the Overleaf, put on the same folder as `.tex` file.

Comment: Thank you very much let me try out and give feedback.